# Get kubectl credentials in Azure

Tags: azure-aks

I have created a K8s service (cluster) on Azure Portal.

I can retreive my credentials with this command (works fine):

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myAKSCluster
```

But i want to know how i can download credentials from azure portal web interface (UI). Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

K8s credentials are not available from the portal UI. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough-portal#connect-to-the-cluster

You can connect to the cluster via cloud CLI rather than your local terminal.